# Cannot create a database on localhost/phpymyadmin using xampp

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

[image]

Hi everyone, I was having trouble with my xampp, I could not create a new database as shown in the picture above. Has anyone encountered this? your help would be appreciated thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is because you don't have proper privileges to create a new database.

Perhaps you're connecting as the anonymous user, or perhaps your expected user account specifies a different host field than what you're connecting as.

From the home page, you can see the user, connection type, and other information. You should cross reference this to the XAMPP documentation to see if you're connecting as the correct user (by default, MySQL/MariaDB uses username 'root' with a blank password and usually restricts external connections, but XAMPP probably does something different).